# How do you sort out an array in java without using a sorting algorithm, while ignoring other values?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

```
int timeTakenInSeconds[] = {600, -1, 500, 430, 412, -1, 0, 0, 0};
```

I want to sort this array from smallest to biggest. Simple, the problem is I need to ignore -1 and 0. My idea was to use a bubble sort to sort the array and place it in a new array. But I'm finding trouble sorting this array while ignoring `0` and `-1`.

Still a bit new to arrays, so I was wondering if anyone has suggestions?

Comment: And what does "ignore" mean? Keep them on their index or append them at the start/end of the sorted array?

Comment: You only have to ignore -1 and 0 or all number smaller then 1? And you would like to sort them with losing the time cutting them at the end, right? So having a sort algorithm and removing those number in the end is not an option. You could go through a for loop and remove unwanted values and then do the sort. This would O(n2) + O(n).

Comment: Does it have to be done in place, or are you allowed to create another array? Can you use `ArrayList`?

Comment: By "ignore" I mean in my new array it would look like 
int arr[] = {412, 430, 500, 600, 0, 0, 0, -1, -1};

Comment: That's not ignoring 0 and 1, that's sorting using a non-standard ordering. You could write a `Comparator<Integer>` for this ordering.

Comment: But with `0, 0, 0, -1, -1` you aren't ignoring them, since this is also sorted (descending),

Comment: yes thats precisely the case. My wording was a bit off, sorry. I'd rather use a sorting array but our lecturer advice us to use another method. Sorting the 0 and -1 at the end is what I finding difficult. But I will try all the suggestions mentioned, thanks.

Comment: You can't sort without using a sorting algorithm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you consider my compact solution (Java 8).

```
Arrays.stream(timeTakenInSeconds)        // turn the array into the stream
      .filter(i -> i != 0 && i != -1)    // throw away 0 and -1
      .sorted()                          // make a sorted order by default
      .toArray();                        // put into an array
```

The second part is similar to the first one. Then to merge 2 arrays you may use, for example, `ArrayUtils.addAll(T[], T...)` from Apache.

Comment: This is only a "half solution" ;P. The second half needs to ignore everything that isn't 0 or -1, sort that descending and that join the resulting array with the one of the first "half" to create the result OP expects: `{412, 430, 500, 600, 0, 0, 0, -1, -1};`. But the first half is already a quite nice solution.

Answer (score 2):

Filter, then apply your sort yourself:

```
int[] newArray = Arrays.stream(timeTakenInSeconds).filter(i -> i > 0).toArray();
customBubbleSort(newArray);
```

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT** Updated to sort positive integers in ascending order and integers less than or equal to 0 in descending order. 
Using an `Integer` comparator:

```
    int timeTakenInSeconds[] = {600, -1, 500, 430, 412, -1, 0, 0, 0};
    Comparator<Integer> comparator = Integer::compare;

    //split the positive and negative integers since they'll be sorted differently.
    //Ascending order is the easiest.
    int[] positiveInts = IntStream.of(timeTakenInSeconds).filter(i -> i > 0).sorted().toArray();
    int[] negativeInts = IntStream.of(timeTakenInSeconds).filter(i -> i <= 0).toArray();

    //And now for discending order for negative integers.
    List<Integer> list = IntStream.of(negativeInts).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
    Integer[] sortedNegative = list.stream().sorted(comparator.reversed()).toArray(Integer[]::new);

    //Now overwrite timeTakenInSeconds with the correct values.
    int i = 0;
    for (int val : positiveInts) {
        timeTakenInSeconds[i] = val;
        i++;
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < sortedNegative.length; j++) {
        timeTakenInSeconds[i] = sortedNegative[j];
        i++;
    }
```

Printing this with:

```
for (int j : timeTakenInSeconds) {
        System.out.print(j + " ");
}
```

Sample run:

```
run:
412 430 500 600 0 0 0 -1 -1 
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Comment: `{412, 430, 500, 600, 0, 0, 0, -1, -1}` is expected

Comment: @AndrewTobilko right, didn't catch that since it's in the coments. I didn't downvote you. But if I had to guess it's because you only answered half the question.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution that sorts the array in place and doesn't require anything sophisticated from recent versions of Java.

```
public static void weirdSort(int arr[]) {
    int zeros = 0;
    int minusOnes = 0;
    int index = 0;
    for (int a : arr) {
        switch (a) {
            case 0:
                zeros++;
                break;
            case -1:
                minusOnes++;
                break;
            default:
                arr[index++] = a;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < zeros; i++)
        arr[index++] = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < minusOnes; i++)
        arr[index++] = -1;
    Arrays.sort(arr, 0, arr.length - zeros - minusOnes);    // Replace with bubble sort
}
```

Comment: Plus 1 because I don't fancy the new sophisticated stuff.

Comment: @Ceelos Thanks. This will almost certainly be faster than any stream solution as well.